# Emacs opens ODT file as zip archive

Tags: org-export, odt

When using org export, if I expert to ODT and open, Emacs opens the file internally, as an archive.

I want it to open the ODT file in Libreoffice.

what do I need to change to do that?

Comment: C-c C-e o O from an opened org file and the odt file is created and opened with LibreOffice. How did you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your are on `Linux` ...

Based on https://kjambunathan.github.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Configuration,  add the following to your init file

```lisp
;; (setcdr (assq 'system org-file-apps-defaults-gnu) "xdg-open %s")
(setcdr (assq 'system org-file-apps-gnu) "xdg-open %s")

(advice-add 'org-open-file :around
            (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
              ;; Work around a weird problem with xdg-open.
              (let ((process-connection-type nil))
                (apply orig-fun args))))
```

Then `C-c C-e o O` (small-o and capital-O) will open the file in `LibreOffice`.

---

The above snippet tells `org` that `xdg-open` is the `system` command for opening ODT or any other file (that org-mode doesn't know about)

`gnu` in `org-file-apps-gnu` tells you that you are configuring a Linux like system.

If you are on some other OSes, say Windows, find the configuration variable (=the counterpart of `org-file-apps-gnu`) that sets the `system` command for opening files, and change it to `open` (=or any other equivalent command)

In recent versions of Emacs `browse-url-of-dired-file` (=`W` in `dired-mode`) does the `open` in a system-specific way.  IIRC, you can use a `Elisp` form (instead of a `*shell*` command for configuring the open command)

I have no experience with non-Linux systems ... so I cannot help much with those systems.

---

Start from `M-x customize-variable org-file-apps` or consult other related variables `org-file-apps-macos`, `org-file-apps-windowsnt`

Answer (score 0):

When you run vanilla Emacs without configuration, `odt` files will open as a buffer if you have OpenOffice installed. See: https://lucidmanager.org/productivity/reading-ebooks-with-emacs/

It seems that some parts of Org mode modifies the `auto-mode-alist` variable that associated Open Office formats with `archive-mode`.

A workaround is to evaluate:

```
(use-package ox-odt
  :ensure nil
  :config
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
               '("\\.\\(?:OD[CFIGPST]\\|od[cfigpst]\\)\\'"
                 . doc-view-mode-maybe)))
```

This line corrects the bug in `ox-odt.el` which overrides the defaults.

Comment: Update: Org mode developers confirmed the bug and are working to fix it.